# jquery on() not working on ajax loaded element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have html table loaded via ajax on a page. Now I want to manipulate the table via jquery. So I used  on() function, the problem is that I need to  pass an event as on of the parameters to it in order to make it do something

for eg:

```
 $(document).on("click", "table#cal", function(event){
    alert("loaded");
   });
```

Is there any other way where  as soon table is loaded I can do something like prepending data etc rather than having to 'click' it?

Comment: why not add the code after table is loaded in the loading function? How are you loading the table? $.ajax()?

Comment: no not .ajax() the xmlhttprequest method, but now I think I will try .ajax() as richard suggested...

Answer (score 4):

Can't you do it in the `.success()` callback of the AJAX call?

```
$.ajax({
    // ajax settings
})
.success(function (m) {
    // get the table data
    // build the table
    // place the table on your DOM
    // get yourself a cup of coffee
    // do backflips
    // feed the dog
    // ...
    // manipulate the table
});
```

Comment: i am using xmlhttp ajax not the jquery ajax for ajax functionality, i am not very fluent in jquery just started learning

Comment: Since you're using jQuery anyway, I'd recommend you use it's AJAX functionalities over raw XHR manips. Even for just the added benefit of better cross browser (cross-IE?) compatibility.